# Why does PopViewControllerAnimated crash unless I use dispatch main queue?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

To give some context, I have a simple UITableViewController that is populating a UITableView with data.  When a row is selected, I go to a detail screen by creating a new instance of my custom UIViewController and push it onto my navigation controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)itemTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [itemTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    NSDictionary *mydata = [self.dataRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NameDetailViewController *NDVC = [[NameDetailViewController alloc] initWithName:[mydata objectForKey:@"Name"]
    AndEmail:[mydata objectForKey:@"Email"]
    AndID:[mydata objectForKey:@"Id"]];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:NDVC animated:YES];
}
```

The detail controller itself has a couple textfields and an update button.  When the update button is pressed I update my model, and then attempt to navigate back to the previous UITableViewController using this:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When I do this, the app crashes I get an error just like the one Nick was getting in a previous SO post: [Error when dismissing view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021107/error-when-dismissing-view-controller) - something about Assertion failure in -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] (I can give more detail on this if need be).

I tried doing a few things before calling the pop to address this

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

As well as using resignFirstResponder on each UITextfield.  Neither of which did anything.

However, I found if I use main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```

It seems to work just fine.  I have no idea why this is, and don't have a very firm understanding of why it is crashing in the first place.  I'm assuming it has something to do with my detail controller attempting to do something after it is removed from the stack.

Anyway I was hoping someone here could help me understand why this seems to work, and if this is even a reasonable way for me to have addressed this problem.

Comment: Is the code running on a background thread at the time? Show a little more code around the pop.

Comment: It's not clear from the code - however it looks like the code is somehow running on a background thread. Any UI update must always be done on the main thread.

Comment: @Wain I don't believe so, but to be honest I'm not completely sure (Apologies for my ignorance).

All I do before the pop is send a request to the salesforce API to update with the data in my text fields on the detail screen.  The detail controller is set up as a delegate for the API call, so upon a successful update is when I attempt to pop the controller.

Does that explain it?  Or would you rather me dump all that code in the original question as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes asynchronous API requests won't call back to the delegate on the main thread. There can be a few reasons for this, but if the callback is not on the main thread then you need to be sure to switch to the main thread before you make *any* update to the UI.

As a check, you can determine if you are currently running on the main thread:

```
if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
    NSLog(@"Yay!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Humph, switching to main");
    dispatch...
}
```